# How to change value of Better ListView Item programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, better-listview

I have a Windows Form application and i needed a table that showed some values that are coming from a COM port and updated them every time a Timer ticks.

I couldn´t set manually the values of a common ListView, it asked for a DataSource and i´m not storing the values in a database, so I decided to use the Better ListView Component.

I managed to set the starter values manually through the Design Mode in Visual Studio, but now i can´t access the Items and Sub-items programatically to set their new values.

Has anyone updated programatically these values successfully? Could share an example?

Comment: Why don't you use `DataGridView` ?

Comment: @Ofiris Well, I tried, but i couldn´t find how to add values to it without a DataSource, i could just add the columns.

Comment: You can set the `DataSource` to be a `List` of `Strings` which updates in each `Timer` tick.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

Comment: @Ofiris It works, thanks! I didn´t know i could use a Collection to add the values, that link helped me a lot with the syntax. Post your comment as an answer and i will accept.

Comment: sure, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `DataSource` to be a `List<String>` which updates in each `Timer` tick.

See this [dataGridView guide](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview)